# Performing an action in a particular area?

Tags: android, touch

How can I perform an action when finger is in a particular area?
I do not want to use Button or TextView or something else.
Can I make something like this:

```
public void onTouch {
if [finger is in set x and y position]{
player.start
} else if[finger is not in a set positon] {
player.release();
}
```

I am working in Android Studio.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you googled this before posting it here ? if yes please paste the code you tried.

Comment: It's covered by the Android Developers guide in great detail: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: please explain what you want to do ? what do you mean by "How can I perform an action when finger is in a particular area". that area include some layout . so please explain what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to make a guitar app, and play sounds on a finger's slide over strings@LoveAndroid

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any research effort

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Override your `Activity`'s `onTouch()` method.

```
public void onTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    int left, top, right, bottom;   // Don't forget to initialize with your desired coordinates.

    Rect rectangle = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);

    if (rectangle.contains(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY())) {
        // Perform your action here.
    }

    super.onTouch(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onTouchListener on any View or ViewGroup or its subclasses.

Here is a simple example to show how to track touch actions:

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // action when on touch action is down pressed
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN, location:x" + x + ",y:" + y);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        // action when on touch action is moving
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE, location:x" + x + ",y:" + y);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // action when on touch action is up
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP, location:x" + x + ",y:" + y);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</RelativeLayout>
```